# How to Display different value in dropdown block after making selection from dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular-bootstrap

I am having a dropdown which I have created using "ng-option". Suppose I am having strings in dropdown options such as "JOHN", "MIKE","RONALDO".... Now if i select any one of them , it will be displayed in dropdown block. But if I want only 2 characters ex. "JO"  for john "MI" for mike to get displayed in dropdown block and full string in dropdown options what should i do?

I am using Angular 1 and is there any other way than adjusting CSS width for dropdown block?

Comment: What do you mean by dropdown block???

Answer (score 0):

Set the a fixed width or min-width in the CSS.

```
<select class="dropdownA">
  <option>JOHN</option>
  <option>MIKE</option>
  <option>RONALDO</option>
</select>
```

OR ng-option:

```
<select ng-options="item by object" 
ng-model="selected" 
class="dropdownA"></select>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdownA {
     min-width: 200px;
}
```